# Автомонтирование в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Только начинаю изучать Symfony, не могу справиться с проблемой. Хочу попробовать автомонтирование, но Symfony выдаёт ошибку о том, что класс не существует.

HelloController (\src\Controller\HelloController.php):

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\GreetingGenerator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HelloController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route ("/hello/{name}")
     */

     public function index($name, GreetingGenerator $greeting)
     {
        $info = $greeting->getRandomGreeting($name);
        return $this->render('index.html.twig',
        [
            'info' => $info
        ]);
     }
}
```

GreetingGenerator (\src\GreetingGenerator.php):

```
<?
namespace App;

class GreetingGenerator
{
    public function getRandomGreeting($name)
    {
        $greetings = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Hey'];
        return $greetings[random_int(0,count($greetings) - 1)].', '.$name;
    }
}
```

Полностью сообщение об ошибке выглядит так:
Cannot resolve argument $greeting of "App\Controller\HelloController::index()": Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\HelloController::index()": the $greeting argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "App\GreetingGenerator".

Использовал команду php bin/console debug:autowiring --all, которая сообщила мне следующее:
The following classes & interfaces can be used as type-hints when autowiring:

App\Controller\DefaultController

App\Controller\HelloController

App\GreetingGenerator

App\Kernel (kernel)

Как я понимаю, это означает, что я могу использовать для автомонтирования свой класс.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Возможно надо почистить кеш.

Comment: Чистил. Не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Есть три варианта:

1. Перенесите это в параметры контроллера и далее присвойте свойству класса (самый простой, всё будет сделано автоматически).
2. Если хотите оставить в текущей реализации, то вам нужно определить ваш сервис в services.yaml и явно указать его как аргумент метода контроллера (контроллер необходимо будет тоже [зарегистрировать как сервис](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html)).
3. Напишите и [зарегистрируйте новый ArgumentResolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html#adding-a-custom-value-resolver).

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись. Всё оказалось куда прозаичнее: я просто не short tag, как видно во втором примере кода, поэтому Symfony не воспринимал мой файл. После того, как стал использовать обычный <?php, всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело было в shot tag php. Нужно было использовать обычный тэг. Я использую для тестирования встроенный сервер symfony, который запускаю с помощью symfony:start. Видимо, в настройках сервера отключен флаг short_open_tag.